# How to match images with unknown rotation differences

Tags: image-processing

I have a collection of about 3000 images that were taken from camera suspended from a weather balloon in flight. The camera is pointing a different direction in each image but is generally aimed down, so all the images share a significant area (40-50%) with the previous image but at a slightly different scale and rotated an arbitrary (and not consistent) amount. The image metadata includes a timestamp, so I do know with certainty the correct order of images and the elapsed time between each.

I want to process these images into a single video. If I simply string them together it will be great for making people seasick, but won't really capture the amazingness of the set :)

The specific part I need help with is finding the rotation of the image from the previous image. Is there a library somewhere that can identify regions of overlap between two images when the images themselves are rotated relative to each other? If I can find 2-3 common points (or more), I can do the remaining calculations to determine the amount of rotation and the offset so I can put them together correctly. Alternately, if there is a library that calculates both of those things for me, that would be even better.

I can do this in any language, with a slight preference for either Java or Python. The data is in Hadoop, so Java is the most natural language, but I can use scripting languages as well if necessary.

Since I'm new to image processing, I don't even know where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem like this you could look into SIFT. This algorithm detects local features in images. OpenCV has an implementation of it, you can read about it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html).

You could also try SURF, which is a similar type of algorithm. OpenCV also has this implemented, you can read about that [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=surf#SURF%20%3a%20public%20Feature2D).